# lubuntu firefox toggle fullscreen - the menu bar will not come back

Tags: firefox, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu with firefox in place of chromium and I experience the following problem: when I press F11 the application goes to fullscreen mode but when I subsequently press F11 the application will only partially exit fullscreen, since the menu bar is totally hidden and the tabs/toolbar appear only when I move the mouse close to the titlebar.
Other applications fullscreen (e.g. geany) do not have this problem, is this a bug? is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested with Ubuntu and I have the same issue.  I tested with windows, and no problem, so I would think it a bug.  there is 2 ways that you can use as a workaround:

1) Type about:config in the address bar and look for:

browser.fullscreen.autohide;false

what that will do is keep the firefox button and tabs visible

2) [Take a look at this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-to-use-full-screen)

Hope that this helps

Comment: Thank you, this solution causes the menu to never be hidden, well done!